# how to check for a newer gem version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have the following in my `Gemfile`:

`gem 'rspec-rails', '2.8.1'`

Is there a command available which indicates if there is a more update version available (or maybe list all versions)?

I understand that [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails) does list current versions.

I looked at `bundle update` (http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page40) but it doesn't seem to have a "dry-run" option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gem outdated -r |grep rspec-rails` (see `gem help outdated`)

In your code you can write something like that:

```
if `gem outdated -r`.include? "rspec-rails"
  # ....
end
```